# Degrafa drawing tools - do they exist?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, svg, mxml, degrafa

I'm trying to find an easy way to use degrafa with MXML. I'm no artist and creating graphics using code just seems very wrong when you can't visualise what is needed to make the required art work.
What I'm after is a tool that can take an SVG graphic and convert to suitable MXML tags so that I can copy/paste them into a MXML file.

There is meant to be a video about pulling the SVG data out and placing into a MXML file on the degrafa site, but it isn't available now.

So does anyone know if there is a tool for this, or know of any tutorials on pulling out the svg data and turning it into MXML code.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question that may have an answer:

[Stack Overflow - Is there a SVG to MXML converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702557/is-there-a-svg-to-mxml-converter)

Also why not just use Adobe Flash to create your graphics? Or at least layout your graphics. That's what it's there for.

Comment: Degrafa gives me total control over the colours etc, flash CS3 doesn't do this easily (plus I do not have a licensed copy to use at the moment). So lets just say I want a LED button with a bit of sparkle to it (not a plain circle) and it can be any colour then with degrafa I can change its colours with code and flash can't do this (easily).
I read somewhere that changing the FXG code to Degrafa code is simpler than SVG to Degrafa so I'm going to give that a go.

Comment: Actually, it's really easy. The end result of what you would create in Flash is a sprite or movieclip, and you can apply a ColorTransform to it - off you go!